# AddView error, Just show the first element

Tags: java, android, view, addition

Let's say I have a LinearLayout, and I want to add two View to it. The first one contain editText, and the other one contain listview. I have been try code in java follows:

```
    EditText inputViaText;
    ListView historyInput;
    protected static LinearLayout askTextLayout = null;

    askTextLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    askTextLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    askTextLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    inputViaText =  new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams askTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    historyInput = new ListView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams historyInputParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,70);

    askTextLayout.addView(historyInput,historyInputParams);
    askTextLayout.addView(inputViaText,askTextParams);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameAskTextParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addContentView(askTextLayout, frameAskTextParams);
```

But, It just show the first one that i add. So when i code like follows:

```
     askTextLayout.addView(historyInput,historyInputParams);
     askTextLayout.addView(inputViaText,askTextParams);
```

It just show listView. When i code like follows:

```
     askTextLayout.addView(inputViaText,askTextParams);
     askTextLayout.addView(historyInput,historyInputParams);
```

It just show edittext. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in oncreate Method of your activity

```
context = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setWeightSum(100);
        ListView v1 = new ListView(context);
        v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                50);
        p1.weight = 90;
        v1.setLayoutParams(p1);
        EditText v2 = new EditText(context);
        v2.setText("Hello");
        v2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                50);
        p2.weight = 10;
        v2.setLayoutParams(p2);
        linearLayout.addView(v1, p1);
        linearLayout.addView(v2, p2);
        View view = new View(MainActivity.this);

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        container.addView(linearLayout);
        container.addView(view);


Write this in activity_main:

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where this linear id come from?   "container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);"